# Xcode does not complete enum values parameters if Enum name is not written, but accepts them

Tags: swift, enums, autocomplete, xcode6

do I have some problems with my Xcode installation or is it normal that it does not offer a list of enum values when calling a function/method that accepts an Enum if you start typing a *.* without entering the Enum name? Look at the example below:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case AAA
    case BBB
}

func testFunc(value : MyEnum) {
    println(value.hashValue)
} 

testFunc(.BBB)
```

Xcode accepts the call *testFunc(.BBB)* because it know that *testFunc* wants a *MyEnum* value, but as I write *testFunc(.* then it offers no completion. I think it would be useful to avoid typing the enum name just to see the possible values when the enum name is not necessary.

Comment: That's normal, noone gets autocompletion for just `.` I also wish there were though

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your XCode is ok. You can force intellisense anytime by pressing `Esc` to see if there are any completions after typing `.`.

**Edit**: As of XCode 7, intellisense for enums is working.

Comment: No, it does not offer any completion.

Comment: Yes, as I already mentioned it is the way things are now. I just provided you a way to check if there are any or not.

Comment: It's broken still in the latest XCode